# How to configure multi-monitor docking setup so that it just works

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, docking

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Thinkpad T540p using an Ultra Dock with two attached monitors. The Thinkpad is built with Intel graphics; the monitors are attached via DVI and HDMI respectively, and show up as DP2-1 and DP2-2 under xrandr. The laptop screen shows up as eDP1.

When undocked, I use the laptop screen. When docked, the laptop is shut and I use the two monitors.

The problem is that when docked, the Ubuntu login screen only shows up on the laptop's screen. I need to move my monitors out of the way, open the laptop, log in, then shut the laptop and resume work on the main monitors.

There's a similar problem when resuming after a suspend. I suspend the laptops every day, undock it and lock it away. The next morning I pop it into the dock and resume it. However it doesn't activate the monitors attached to the dock until I open the laptop, whereupon I can unlock it. I then shut the laptop and it stops using the laptop screen.

**Is there a standard way of configuring Ubuntu so that it automatically only uses available attached monitors and doesn't try to use the laptop screen when the lid is shut and other monitors are attached?** In particular, login and lock (post resume) screens.

Note that to get this setup to use both monitors in the first place and not the laptop screen, I had to run xrandr manually:

```
xrandr --output DP2-1 --primary --output eDP1 --off
```

The GUI configuration only saw one dock-attached monitor initially and didn't let me configure either; it's like it only saw DP2, and didn't recognize displayport daisy chaining.